# Instagram API approval

Tags: instagram-api

I'm thinking of developing a personal brand application, that could help users better interact with their followers on Instagram. 
Based on the number of likes and comments, I would display a top of people who interacted with you the most and make suggestions on which of their profiles you should add likes/comments in order to keep their interest.

Do you think this could get approved or do you have some similar experiences with the approval process?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my understanding that your app has to fit into one of the use cases stated at the top of [this page](https://www.instagram.com/developer/). Also, your description seems to fit into the second category of

> help brands and advertisers understand/manage their audience.

By this, I'd say your app should be approved, but I have no experience with Instagram API approval.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your answer. I'm too hoping I would get into the second category . If I don't get other opinions from someone with experience on this, I'll flag this as the answer.

Comment: So, did you get approved?

Comment: I'm still in research phase.